# Problem validating a phone number beginning with 256 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a phone number beginning with 256 and the whole phone number should be a maximum of 12 characters, an example of the phone number is **256732111890** I am using the following regex which seems not to work

```
^(?:[256]●?){6,14}[0-9]$
```

Comment: ^256\d{9}$ if it works, i can explain it on answer (test: https://regex101.com/r/TL1sEs/1)

Comment: ^256\d{7,9}$ Assuming min length 10 and max length 12

Comment: @lucas_7_94 Thanks alot it works fine,,,regex confuses me ,, is it possible to create a regex that compares 2 input fields of dates  ( and validates that the departure date should be filled either the current date the user fills the form or any date in the future and the return date should be a date after departure date) ?

Comment: What is ● in your regex?

Comment: @rv7 Thanks,,the question has been answered,,, would you mind helping me  create a regex that compares 2 input fields of dates  ( and validates that the departure date should be filled either on the current date the user is filling the form or any date in the future and the return date must be a date after departure date) ?

Comment: Using regex for that, is not a suitable choice. I would handle that coding. Also, for that, you need to create another thread.

Comment: @lucas_7_94 Thanks alot,,, let me give it a shot, will create a thread  if I have issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post the pattern, explaining here.

pattern: `^256\d{9}$`

Where

- `^` = asserts the start of the line
- `256` = matches the string 256
- `\d{9}` = matches any number 9 times (exact) after finding '256'.
- `$` = the line must end after finding the 9 numbers.

Also, a good alternative is `^256\d{7,9}$` who was posted by @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi who differs on my pattern:

- `\d{7,9}`: matches any number between 7 and 9 times after finding '256'.